# Firebase Cloud Messaging : push notification and navigate to specific page of application

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging for my android application. I was using GCMBaseIntentService for Push Notification last time. I found Firebase Cloud Messaging, FirebaseMessagingService is different with GCMBaseIntentService(). For GCMBaseIntentService, onMessage() function is always been called when application received the push notification. I can manipulate the data received and navigate to specific page when I click on the push notification.

However, I realized that onMessageReceived() in FirebaseMessagingService is not been called. May I know how can I navigate to specific of application when I receive push notification. The problem is I need to navigate to different page in my application based on the content of my Push Notification received.

The following is my code

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeControllerActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **data message** instead of the **notification**. The data message always load the class onMessageReceived.

Comment: The main problem is onMessageReceived() function is not been called at all. My logcat in android studio does not display my log message in  onMessageReceived() function. Or else any other solution for me to get specific content of PushNotitication so that I can navigate to specific page of Application

Comment: please check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: i think you are sending notification mesage

Comment: That means this is regardless with front end android. I have to modify my backend server side scripting?

Comment: Yes, you have to

Comment: Glad it helped you, if it solved your problem accept it as answer so the question will be closed.